# Accidentally deleted Windows 10 boot partition

Tags: windows-10, grub, bootloader

Today, I wanted to install **Kubuntu** alongside **Windows 10**, but  I got an error that had something to do with an existing GRUB on one of my hard drives.

I removed the partition which I thought was GRUB, but it actually was the Windows boot loader which I removed.

Kubuntu installed just fine, but now I can't boot into Windows anymore.

I've tried running `bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr`, `Bootrec.exe /FixMbr` (*Which returned successful*) & `Bootrec.exe /FixBoot` (*Which returned an error, I think it was that it couldn't find a file*).

But I still can't boot into Windows.

Comment: You may have to rebuild the BCD store also...http://blog.d0zingcat.xyz/2015/09/28/Windows/How%20to%20repair%20the%20EFI%20Bootloader%20in%20Windows%2010/

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://peter.upfold.org.uk/blog/2013/02/28/restore-windows-8-bootloader/) this issue arises from not having the C drive set as the active partition.

For more information on dual booting I recommend reading [this](http://www.optimizingpc.com/install/multiboot_bootmanager.html).

Notably,

> The **active partition** is the primary partition which the computer boots from to load the bootmanager on the boot sector of this partition. In most cases, the active partition receives the disk letter C: in Windows, but this is not always the case..

*Important: UEFI differs from MBR*

Comment: I followed the steps from the guide you linked, but it still didn't work. I'm sure  that drive C is set as active. I tried restoring factory settings, but both the one where you keep your files and the complete reset one didn't work. It said there's a required partition missing. (I'm not sure if that's what the message is in English since my PC is set to Dutch)

Comment: I don't know what I did, but at this point, when I type bootrec.exe /fixmbr, it tells me that there are 0 Windows installations found. So I am just going to copy everything that I want to keep to another HDD in Kubuntu, and completely reinstall Windows. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I now go into my Windows drive, it's empty. Something formatted the entire drive, so there's no point in trying anymore, I just have to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to copy everything that I want to keep to a new HDD, but my original Windows drive was completely empty. I'm just going to reinstall it, and hope it works then.

Answer (score -1):

If none of that worked then there is probably no recovering your Windows install. You may be able to use disk forensics tools such as Recuva or a tool included with Kali Linux to recover your lost data.